# AJAX isn't returning any data

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, json

still fairly new to AJAX. I feel I'm not grasping it completely. I want to submit partial data  to the server, perform an SQL query and return the results. This is what I have so far:

**jQuery**

```
j$('select[name=agent_Name]').change(function(event) {
     event.preventDefault();
     var agentID = j$(this).val();
     post_data = {'agent_ID':agentID};
     console.log("About to post data to the server");
    j$.post('../include/booking_Modify.php', post_data, function(response){  
        if(response.type == 'AgDEpCd'){
            output = response.text;
            console.log(output);
        }
        if(response.type == 'error'){
            output = response.text;
            console.log(output);
        }
    }, 'json');     
});
```

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start();
require("../include/conn.php");
dbopen();
//check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
    if(!isset($_POST["agent_ID"]))
    {
        $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Nothing was selected!'));
        die($output);
    }

    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT AgDEpCd FROM AGENTS WHERE AgentID = ?");
    $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST["agent_ID"]);   // bind variables to the parameter
    $stmt->execute();

    $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
    $AgDEpCd = $row['AgDEpCd'];
    $stmt->close();
    $output = json_encode(array('type'=>'AgDEpCd', 'text' => $AgDEpCd));
    die($output);
?>
```

I checked to make sure:
the file path was correct. 
var agentID = j$(this).val(); actually grabs a value, which it does
Manually entered the SQL query into PHPMyAdmin to ensure I was retrieving results.
I can't seem to return anything from the server. I'm not sure this is even possible. Please help!

Comment: its missing a `]`. is this a typo? `'select[name=agent_Name'`

Comment: @Ghost Good catch. But no, I typed the first few lines out.

Comment: also, just a shot in the dark, check if `console.log(typeof response);` and check the result. or just `console.log(response)`

Comment: just a suggestion: if you want to test for output, keep your console.logs outside if blocks

Comment: @Ghost I popped that line of code just after "function(response){ " and nothing showed. Bizzare.

Comment: Just try echo $output before die and change die($output) to die();

Comment: @WisdmLabs I did as you suggested and nothing is still outputting.

Comment: Is the issue just that the jQuery event isn't making the AJAX request? If you request the AJAX file in your browser do you see the JSON?

Comment: @doublesharp That's what I was thinking. That it's not even making the request. I know it's finding the correct file. But I don't know how to test is the call is working or not other than echoing what's in the PHP file "booking_Modify.php"

Comment: you can make calls to 'error_log()` to see where it is getting in your PHP

Answer (score 1):

Normally I will do just echo and exit, short and faster. In beforehand entering response, just `console.log` and check out if it return any. If it doesn't just check your php code, there is other error than the encoding output. Try it.

```
 <?php
    session_start();
    require("../include/conn.php");
    dbopen();
    //check $_POST vars are set, exit if any missing
        if(!isset($_POST["agent_ID"]))
        {
            echo json_encode(array('type'=>'error', 'text' => 'Nothing was selected!'));
            exit;
        }

        $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT AgDEpCd FROM AGENTS WHERE AgentID = ?");
        $stmt->bind_param('i', $_POST["agent_ID"]);   // bind variables to the parameter
        $stmt->execute();

        $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        $AgDEpCd = $row['AgDEpCd'];
        $stmt->close();
        echo json_encode(array('type'=>'AgDEpCd', 'text' => $AgDEpCd));
        exit;
    ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not assigned result to $result variable.

It should be,

```
$result = $stmt->execute();
```

Comment: I added the following code in but I am still not seeing any returned results!

Answer (score 0):

Just echo the result set at the end of the php script. 
It will be assigned to the ajax response data.

```
$data = array('type'=>'AgDEpCd', 'text' => $AgDEpCd);
echo json_encode($data);
```